# Functional equation involving composition and exponential

Tags: calculus, functions, exponential-function, functional-equations, function-and-relation-composition

My main question is how to solve this functional equation:
$f(f(x)) = e^x$.

The context within which this came up was when I was attempting to extend the notation of the inverse function ($f^{-1}$) to include something like $f^{0.5}$, where composition of the functions adds the superscript numbers.

In this extension $f^{1} = f$ and $f^0$ is the identity function, so $(f^{0.5} \circ f^{0.5}) = f$.
So as an extra question, for which classes of real-valued functions does there exist such an $f^{0.5}$? It's fairly easy to see that for every polynomial function with a single term, represented by $f(x) = ax^n$, $f^{0.5}(x) = \sqrt[\sqrt n + 1]{a}x^{\sqrt n}$. I'm not sure how to proceed from there though.

Comment: Is it possible that your definition of $f(x)$, in terms of the behavior of $f[f(x)]$ makes $f(x)$ well defined, yet at the same time, there is no *closed form* (whatever that means in this context) expression for $f(x)$?  It seems to me that you must (somehow) prove that $f(x)$ is uniquely defined.  As for there being no closed form (whatever that means), I am clueless here.

Comment: You're looking for the functional square root. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_square_root

Comment: @user2661923 I'm not worried about whether multiple functions that fit the definition of $f$ exist, but that would be an interesting follow up question (intuition leans on the side of only 1 such function existing). I'm looking for any solution whatsoever. As for it being closed form, I've got no idea how to prove anything about that either.

Comment: @CyclotomicField thank you so much. I searched before to find something that answered my question but didn't find that.

Comment: My point was that if (1) you didn't care about whether there is a closed form expression, (2) CyclotomicField had not responded, and (3) you could prove that $f$ is uniquely defined, then I would argue that you are **done.**  That is, (hypothetically) you would have unambiguously defined $f$, and would not care about more elegant representations of $f$.

Comment: Solved by H. Kneser, and not for beginners  http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002175851  ... I know what to do when there is a real fixpoint; Kneser combined two complex fixpoints

Comment: Perhaps it is interesting for you to read the introductionary remarks in my homepage http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/index.htm which I dedicated to my study of the "tetration", where on of the roots of interest have as well been the problem which you have stated here. I came to the perspective of iteration of functions which admit a defining power series and arrived at the Schröder's solution. Perhaps two of the rather technical articles might interest you most: the small treatize of "continuous functional iteration" and that "comparision of 4 methods". If you like something of this, tell.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12081/does-the-exponential-function-have-a-compositional-square-root  has a lot of additional infos & links